# retry insert 3 times only when error code 403002 occurs

Tags: c#, json.net, polly, retry-logic

I came to know through `Polly` I can re-try the execution up to multiple configurable time like below example,

```
 Policy
.Handle<SqlException>(ex => ex.Number == 1205)
.Or<ArgumentException>(ex => ex.ParamName == "example")
.WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
.Execute(DoSomething);
```

In my case below I am doing JSON serialization and all to find the error code `403002` and only on this error I want to re-try my code `await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(new Message());` with a configuration time.

How to achieve this with Polly?

```
try
        {
            await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(new Message());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errorMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message;

            if (errorMessage != null)
            {
                dynamic error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(errorMessage);
                if (error != null && error.errorCode == 403002)
                {
                    // want to re-try again 'await deviceClient.SendEventAsync'
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Other error occurred : {error}");
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be late to the party, but let me put my 2 cents here.

[user1672994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672994/user1672994)'s suggested solution will not work for `SendEventAsync`, because the policy definition is created for sync function whereas your to-be-decorated one is async.

There is simple fix for that: use `WaitAndRetryAsync` instead.

---

I would also suggest to extract your *should trigger retry* delegate into a separate method to make your policy definition short and concise like this:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
  .Handle<Exception>(ShouldTriggerRetry)
  .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

```
bool ShouldTriggerRetry(Exception ex)
{       
    var errorMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)) return false;
    var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(errorMessage);

    var shouldTrigger = error?.errorCode == 403002;
    if(!shouldTrigger) _logger.LogError($"Other error occurred : {error}");
    return shouldTrigger;
}
```

---

One final thought: As I can see in your code you have a `finally` block. If you need to do some cleanup between the retry attempts then you should do that inside `onRetry` or `onRetryAsync` delegate (depends on your cleanup code: sync or async).

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
  .Handle<Exception>(ShouldTriggerRetry)
  .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), SyncCleanup);

//...

void SyncCleanup(Exception ex, TimeSpan sleep)
{
   //...
}
```

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
  .Handle<Exception>(ShouldTriggerRetry)
  .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), AsyncCleanup);

//...

Task AsyncCleanup(Exception ex, TimeSpan sleep)
{
    //...
}
```

`WaitAndRetryAsync` has 19 overloads so, you might need to scrutinise them if you need to access for example the retry counter or the `Context` in your `onRetry(Async)` delegate.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> Where should I put `await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(new Message())`

In case of Polly you define a policy and then you use it. The above code was just the definition. The usage looks like this:

```
await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(new Message()));
```

or like this

```
await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => deviceClient.SendEventAsync(new Message()));
```

> Which block I should put my code plus after 3 fail I want to log message and initialize some variable

If all your attempts fail (4 in your case: the initial attempt + 3 retries) then the retry policy will throw the original exception

```
try
{
    await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(new Message()));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError(ex, "Operation failed 4 times");
}
```

Comment: your solution looks interesting, one question, where I should put `await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(new Message());` ?

Comment: Which block I should put my code plus after 3 fail I want to log message and initialize some variable ? how to do it?

Comment: @user584018 I've updated my post, please check my answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but when debugger reached to `ShouldTriggerRetry`, it's says semaphore disposed and my exception messages is null, could you please tell how to fix it?

Comment: @user584018 I assume (based on your code) that whenever the SendEventAsync fails then it destroys the underlying resources. In other words the deviceClient might not be reusable in case of failure. You might need to create a new client.

Comment: I figured out the error, all works like a charm! you made my day Sir. Big Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can Handle the generic Exception and validate the errorCode to return bool value.

```
Policy
.Handle<Exception>(ex => 
{
    var errorMessage = ex.InnerException?.Message;

    if (errorMessage != null)
    {
         dynamic error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(errorMessage);
         if (error != null && error.errorCode == 403002)
         {
             // want to re-try again 'await deviceClient.SendEventAsync'
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
})
.WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
.Execute(DoSomething);
```

Comment: Please remove those builder method calls that have nothing to do with OP's problem

Comment: @PeterCsala - I used those builder method as they were mentioned in the question. I will remove those now.

Comment: Apologize, I missed that part

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me